# Let $(A)_{4 \times 7}$ and $(B)_{7 \times 4}$ be two matrices then is the following claim true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $(A)_{4 \times 7}$ and $(B)_{7 \times 4}$ Be two matrices such that $AB =  I$

then I need to prove that $\lambda =0$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$ with arithmetic multiplicity $3$

Now, $\operatorname{Rank}(BA) \le  \operatorname{Rank} A  \le 4$

So,

Nullity Of $\text{(BA)} \ge 3$, Since we know that

$\gamma(0) \le \alpha(0)$ ,

($\gamma(0)$ is the geometric multiplicity and $\alpha(0)$ is arithmetic multiplicity)

Using this $\alpha(0) \ge 3$

After this I am stuck, I don't know how to continue after this.

Can anyone please help me here ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For any $x$ in the image (AKA column space, AKA range) of $B$, $BAx = x$.  Use this fact to conclude that $\gamma(1) \geq 4$.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you please explain your hint, I am not getting it .

Comment: What specifically are you not getting?

Comment: We are given $AB = I$ , using this how can I say that $BA(x) = x$

Comment: We can't in general, but we can if we know that $x$ is in the column-space of $B$.  Try to figure out why that makes a difference. Note that $x$ is in the column space of $B$ iff $x = By$ for some vector $y$.

Comment: If you've honestly sit with the problem and this hint for 10 minutes and still feel stuck, I'll write out the rest of the solution.

Comment: Ok, I will try first and then if I feel stuck I will ask for help, Thank you.